# Error while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set

Tags: spring-security

I am implementing a trial oauth resource server for study. I face the below issue when I send a request along with an access token to one of the secured APIs of the resource serve.

An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set.

### My Auth Server Config:

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {
    
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
        .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
    
    http
        // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated 
        // from the authorization endpoint
        .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
            ))
        
        // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
        .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer
            .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/jkws").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        
    // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
    // authorization server filter chain    
    http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
    
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
    http.cors(cors -> cors.disable());
    
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId("oidc-client")
            //.clientSecret("{noop}secret")
            .clientSecret("$2a$04$R.Nl31CwJtKOtCDcE69e8OO0O8ryb8Rx2vhcUS5wde6Zpj2750kt2")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .redirectUri("https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback")
            .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/")
            .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
            .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
            .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
            .build();

    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
}

@Bean
public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
    KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
    RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
    RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
    RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
            .privateKey(privateKey)
            .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .build();
    JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
    return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
}

private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
    KeyPair keyPair;
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
    return keyPair;
}

@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
    return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
}

@Bean
public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
    return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().jwkSetEndpoint("/jwks").build();
}

@Bean
public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtTokenCustomizer() { 
    return (context) -> {
        if (OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType())) { 
            context.getClaims().claims((claims) -> { 
                Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(context.getPrincipal().getAuthorities())
                        .stream()
                        .map(c -> c.replaceFirst("^ROLE_", ""))
                        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), Collections::unmodifiableSet)); 
                claims.put("roles", roles); 
            });
        }
    };
}
```

### My Resource Server config:

```
@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
private String jwkSetUri;

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
            .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
        );
    return http.build();
}

/*
 * http://localhost:8080/.well-known/openid-configuration
 */
@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder
            .withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri)
            .jwsAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256).build();
}
```

### Resource Server properties:

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=http://localhost:8080/jkws

Comment: When you manually go to `http://localhost:8080/jkws` you get?

Comment: Nope. it takes me to the login page. Later I corrected the URL to ---> http://localhost:8080/oauth2/jwks (this one is manually accessible). However, it did not help either. Same issue all over again.

Comment: I get below JSON when I manually access http://localhost:8080/oauth2/jwks

Comment: {
keys: [
{
kty: "RSA",
e: "AQAB",
kid: "36d98ce3-f8a8-4dc8-a603-781df2d959cf",
n: "2JtFYhEglPQwxDltXncyqKmMi4hJpS_sWY0j7hRFOgMKxpbjKhbSPK03u9f6RIBHbLBGo-bvQfs7kdicOeKhHdXA8xHdeyNBt4ztdApE1eVJmSpu3ZnNOuTufUL92IqUl_ZY7i7IcBl3mlqkB19szU1y9ixDSQw6_3yXEBk8eZtd_5XdJ3YUSK3FXslZp4S8MeOHuzNyxn2WPuDX8qT_QqBx5tNcL0XFvIUgopU-5rsMcQwjei016f0Oz8xd0qYeJy7YPMBR2EYd-icTRMfctfi9iUvxE5vXMyO6X0qbopWl7GcC0Yj6pxBV_dkwVmDjJjoUA_kjY7JMbAvybdXLgQ"
}
]
}

Comment: Please do not post code in comments, use the edit button on your question.